# Rails 4 e-commerce customization: Products from existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, customization

I am building an internet shop for collectible items and I am stuck with the e-commerce solution.

One of the biggest difficulties for me is that there are around 100 000 different collectible items, and most info regarding the products in question are parsed from the producer's site. Now the shop itself will operate in the secondary (second-hand) market. So I need a solution, that would allow me to create products based on the existing ActiveRecord objects, or (ideally) use products, that are preconstructed in my custom backend.

The big question is thus. Which is the best approach to e-commerce for this highly custom product model?

- Does, for example, Spree support customization of the product
  creation process? If yes, where can I read about it in detail?
- Is there any solution, that is more suitable for this scenario?
- If I was to develop my own e-commerce solution: where can I find a robust tutorial, or read about the basic architecture and gems
  required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"create products based on the existing ActiveRecord objects" -- that doesn't sound hard, sounds like a rake task

"or (ideally) use products, that are preconstructed in my custom backend" -- not sure what that means.

"Does Spree support customization of the product creation process" -- sure does, but what customization are you talking about? Take look at Spree's Option Types & Option Values, those should be customizable enough to accommodate pretty much anything.